# Virtual Domains or MultiSite Routes in Symfony2

Tags: dns, symfony

I have a project in Symfony2 that supports multiple domains and multiple pages per site all running on the same code base so that we can maintain a single code base.

I could pass all incoming requests to a 'domain controller' bundle and allow the controller determine what domain it is and include appropriate bundles for that domain, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the long way is the only way in this case. Pass all routes to a controller in the first bundle and then divi it up from there (sending them to the proper bundles that would ultimately produce the desired site/pages)

Comment: Could you use Apache to proxy requests from http://domain1/some-page to http://shared-domain/domain1/some-page and use normal routing to do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in Symfony 2.0. However, it's [planned](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1762) for 2.1.

Comment: Actually this has landed for 2.2, which is set for a release in February '13.